# Heroku cedar node app - cannot push master after update to 6.11.1

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

After updating the node server to version 6.11.1 in response to the recent security update email from Heroku, I cannot git push my local master changes any more. The server and app restarted fine after the update.

I have tried deleted and reinstalled all node_modules, committing the changes and the app runs without errors locally but I get the same build failure when trying to deploy the master. The only change I've made to the package.json file is adding the npm version which was previously unspecified.

From the logs the server build fails when installing node modules:

```
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Is force pushing the best/a good solution?

This is the full logs:

```
Counting objects: 18, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 8.80 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 18 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  6.11.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   5.3.0
remote:
remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.11.1...
remote:        Downloading and installing npm 5.3.0 (replacing version 3.10.10)...
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-07-20T22_54_19_003Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to app-name.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git'
```

Thanks.

Comment: I was finally able to push the master to heroku by setting the npm version in package.json file back to 3.10.10. For some reason trying to update npm on the server to 5.3.0 was failing the build.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message after updating to node 6.11.1 and npm 5.3.0. heroku support suggested that I run these commands:

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-repo
heroku repo:purge_cache -a APPNAME
git commit --allow-empty -m "Purge cache"
git push heroku master
```

... where "APPNAME" was the heroku identifier for my app.

**That resolved the error** and I did not have to revert to an earlier version of npm. I've asked for an explanation but they haven't responded yet (just asked a few minutes ago).

**UPDATE 2017-07-27:** heroku support responded and said, "We're still working on the root cause for this but it seems to be fairly intermittent." Now that I have installed the plugin (see above), I am running these steps to update my app:

```
heroku repo:purge_cache -a APPNAME
git push heroku master
```

That's been working reliably for me.